# Highlighting a specific position of a string?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In my TKinter GUI I am trying to highlight a specific character in my text string. I have a string, which I declare as `Stringvar = StringVar()`. Lets say I wanted to highlight the first character of `Stringvar` (i.e. `Stringvar[0]`). How would I do that in TKinter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple script that will highlight text based on the character positions that you give it.

Run the script, hit the 'highlight' button then input your start and end positions in the format 1.0-1.0 .

The first digit refers to the line number. The digit after the decimal place refers to the character position in the line.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkSimpleDialog

def highlight():
    var = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Text Highlighter", "format: x.x-x.x")
    a,b = var.split("-")
    aText.tag_add("bt", a, b)

txt = "First line of text \nSecond line of text \nThird line of text"

lord = tk.Tk()

aText = tk.Text(lord, font=("Georgia", "12"))
aText.grid()

aText.insert(tk.INSERT, txt)

aButton = tk.Button(lord, text="highlight", command=highlight)
aButton.grid()

aText.tag_config("bt", background="yellow")

lord.mainloop()
```

Comment: The format of the index begins with `"1.0"`, not `"0.0"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with text in a text widget. You can't do it in a normal string or in a `StringVar`.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# configure tags which change how characters look
text.tag_configure("red", foreground="red")
text.tag_configure("green", foreground="green")

# insert text, then highlight it in a separate command:
text.insert("1.0", "this is red\n")
text.tag_add("red", "1.0", "2.0")

# insert text and highlight in one command:
text.insert("end", "this is green\n", "green")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have it working as shown above, but that works for every character in the string. Say for the example of "this is red", how can I only highlight the "r" in red? Thanks

Comment: @vsav: `text.insert("end", "r", "red")` or `text.tag_add("red", "1.0", "1.1")`